# send email with link

Tags: php, cakephp, html-email

This code outputs:

```
Call to a member function link() on a non-object
```

What I want is send a link in email. What is wrong with the code? thanks

```
class User extends AppModel {
    public $helpers = array('Html');
    public function sendEmail($email_user, $code) {
            $email = new CakeEmail();
            $email->config('smtp');

            $pwrurl = "http://xxx/users?se=check&mail=".$email_user."&code=".$code;
            $link = $this->Html->link('Link name', $pwrurl, array('target' => '_blank'));
            $email->from(array('xxxn@gmail.com' => 'xxxx'))
            ->to($email_user)
            ->emailFormat('html')
            ->send('My message:: '.$link);
            return true;
        }
}
```

[docs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/helpers.html)

**Update: I get the same error.**

```
App::uses('CakeEmail', 'Network/Email');
App::uses('AppHelper', 'View/Helper');

class AppController extends Controller {
      public $helpers = array('Form', 'Html');

      public function sendEmail($email_user, $codeLink) {
             //same code.
      }
```

}

Comment: `$this->Html` is probably `null`

Comment: you can scratch the "probably" ;) I wonder how people get the idea to include the helpers array in a model...

Comment: @mark, and a possible solution is?

Comment: for starters doing it the cake way. use templates/layouts and only pass down the values/arrays which then will translate into the link in the view ctps (there the html helper is available).

Comment: @ mark, ok. So to send an html link, the only way is doing the html code by hand?

Answer (score 2):

Should probably have this in the controller:

```
class UsersController extends AppController {
   var $name = 'Users';
   var $helpers = array('Html');
   var $components = array('Email');

   function _email($email_user, $code){
      $pwrurl = "http://xxx/users?se=check&mail=".$email_user."&code=".$code;
      $this->Email->from = 'From: Someone';
      $this->Email->to = $email_user;
      $this->Email->subject  = 'Your Subject';
      $this->Email->sendAs = 'html';
      $this->Email->template = 'your_template';
      $this->set('pwrurl', $pwrurl);
      $this->Email->send();
   }
}
```

Then create an e-mail template in views/elements/email/html named the same as your template in the above code.  For this example your_template.ctp.  Compose the message the way you want it to look and where ever you want the link to appear use:

```
$this->Html->link('Link name', $pwrurl, array('target' => '_blank'));
```

Hopefully that helps.

Comment: I will get an undefined variable: pwrurl in template. 
 I think that I only can do $this->HTML->link... in view/users folder.

Comment: If you use $this->set('pwrurl', $pwrurl); the variable will be available in your specified e-mail template.  I ran the code above to make sure it works and I was able to send and receive the link.

Comment: Your example is to cake 1.3 right? Well, the template in cake 2.2 should be placed in view/email/html/template.ctp. I still getting the same error. But if i use a view of users folder then i can use the `$this->Html->link('Link name', $pwrurl, array('target' => '_blank')); properly. 
`

Comment: Yeah sorry about that, I am using cake 1.3. [Cake 2.0][cake] Shows setting the `$email->helpers(array('Html'));` and sending your variables to the email view using `$email->viewVars(array('pwrurl' => $pwrurl));` [cake]: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/email.html

Answer (score 1):

from [here](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/ashevat/2010/03/12/how-to-implament-one-time-password-for-forgot-my-password-and-account-activation-processes):

```
$pwrurl = '<a href="http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] ."/users/otpregister/".$email_user."&code=".$codeLink.'"> Registration link</a>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the above code,  you can try to use the following:

```
App::uses('HtmlHelper', 'View/Helper');
class User extends AppModel {
public function sendEmail($email_user, $code) {
        $email = new CakeEmail();
        $email->config('smtp');

        $pwrurl = "http://xxx/users?se=check&mail=".$email_user."&code=".$code;
        $link = $this->Html->link('Link name', $pwrurl, array('target' => '_blank'));
        $email->from(array('xxxn@gmail.com' => 'xxxx'))
        ->to($email_user)
        ->emailFormat('html')
        ->send('My message:: '.$link);
        return true;
    }
}
```

As because of `$helpers` is a valid data member for the controllers, not for the models. It is also a good alternative to write the `sendEmail()` method in your AppController.php and invoke this method into your controller's method using `$this->sendEmail($user_email, $code);`

[This documentation page](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/app.html#loading-classes) might help you to achieve the same.

Hope it will work for you.

Comment: I get exactly the same error, even if i put the code in controller.